# SQL Group By Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which tracks views of products.

```
TrackId ProductId CreatedOn
1       1         01/01/2011
2       4         01/01/2011
3       4         01/01/2011
4       10        01/01/2011
```

What I want to do is return a dataset which doesn't have two ProductIds next to each other. I.E from the above data set I would want to return:

```
TrackId ProductId CreatedOn
1       1         01/01/2011
2       4         01/01/2011
4       10        01/01/2011
```

I can't use distinct as far as I am aware as this is row based?

Help appreciated.

Comment: You mean "not having productid in two adjacent rows. Adjacent is defined by next/previous Trackid"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a [row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) sequence per ProductID, take the first

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY TrackID) AS rn
    FROM
       MyProductTable
)
SELECT
   TrackId ProductId CreatedOn
FROM
   cte
WHERE
   rn = 1
```

Edit:

If you want to use an aggregate, you need a separate subquery first to ensure consistent results. A straight MIN won't work.

This is based on my comment to the question

> "not having productid in two adjacent rows. Adjacent is defined by next/previous Trackid"

```
SELECT
    M.*
FROM
    myProductTable M
    JOIN
    ( --gets the lowest TrackID for a ProductID
    SELECT ProductID, MIN(TrackID) AS MinTrackID
    FROM myProductTable
    GROUP BY ProductID
    ) M2 ON M.ProductID= M2.ProductID AND M.TrackID= M2.MinTrackID
```

Comment: +1 @izip, if you haven't used CTE's and the ranking functions of SQL 2005+, then learn them. They will serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

You can GroupBy on the TrackID and ProductID and do a Min of the CreatedOn if the date is not important.

```
SELECT TrackID ,ProductID ,MIN(CreatedOn)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY TrackID ,ProductID
```

If the date is the same you can group by all three

```
SELECT TrackID ,ProductID ,CreatedOn
FROM [table]
GROUP BY TrackID ,ProductID ,CreatedOn
```

Comment: I need to return the full dataset.

Comment: @izip: you can't have the "full dataset" returned if you want to remove some rows

Comment: Sorry I meant all columns. CTE way has worked. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(TrackId), ProductId, CreatedOn
from YourTable
group by ProductId, CreatedOn;
```

Comment: What if CreatedOn differs for a given ProductId? Then you have the wrong output...